# Is there a way to make a 2D circular density plot of intensity from x, y, z values; that looks like the stat_density2d plot?

Tags: r, plot, 3d, contour

I'm trying to make a density plot of intensity in a circle, from radial intensity measuements of a bacterial population.

I've looked into various 3D, 2D options to best represent the data.

I effectively want to create something like this:

R code:

df <- tibble(x_variable = rnorm(5000), y_variable = rnorm(5000))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x_variable, y = y_variable)) +
stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..density..), contour = F, geom = 'tile')

However, [what i want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbRJ1.png), from [this is a rough extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLXW8.png), where x and y are radial distances from the center point with a density/contours/shading being representing intensity z.

I'm ok with it being a contour plot, or a 3D plot viewed above. Just feel like i've tried everything, with other examples i'll have surfaces which might overlap and 'submerge' and reappear at different distances. So any advice on how to tackle that would be great.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the geometric relation between x and y?  Are they radial distances for two different attributes with unrelated centres, or are they distances to two circles relative to the same centre, or distances to points relative to something (in which case, why don't the directions matter)?

Comment: x and y are made from the same data: Effectively the x-axis data is just radius values (cm) logged ranging from approx c(0,3cm) with 2574 values in-between. I reflected it in terms of c(-3,3) and intensities have the same amount of values 2574x2 c(3.94-9) ish. When i run the geom_raster command i get : Warning messages: 1: Raster pixels are placed at uneven horizontal intervals and will be shifted. Consider using geom_tile() instead. 2: Raster pixels are placed at uneven vertical intervals and will be shifted. Consider using geom_tile() instead.

Comment: Because your x values are identical to your y values you don’t have the data to create an honest 2d data plot. At best you could create an imagined ‘2d density’ from your 1d density that you have measured.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you are trying to represent x, y, z data as a contour or 2D density plot. In order to do this, your data have to be organized into a regular grid.

My understanding is that the x value in your data represents the radial distance from the center of the bacterial colony and the z value represents the density at that point. This gives us enough information to create a 3D surface, providing that we can assume the colony is perfectly radially symmetrical.

We start by loading in the data, and arrange it by increasing x value:

```r
df <- read.csv('my_data.csv')
df <- df[order(df$x),]
```

Now we create a sequence of radial distances from the centre which encompass our data set and will be used as the x and y co-ordinates of our grid. We need enough points to make the grid smooth, so we will use 300 points along each side of our grid:

```r
radii <- seq(min(df$x), max(df$x), length = 300)
```

Now we can create a grid of all x, y combinations of these points using `expand.grid`, and then find the Euclidean distance from each point to the center:

```r
plot_df        <- expand.grid(x = radii, y = radii)
plot_df$radius <- sqrt(plot_df$x^2 + plot_df$y^2)
```

To get the z value at each grid point, we can use `findInterval`, which will identify the row of our original data frame which is closest to the radius of each grid point. The z value of that row will be the z value of the grid point:

```r
plot_df$z <- df$z[findInterval(plot_df$radius, df$x)]
```

Now we can plot the result using `geom_raster`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(plot_df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_raster() +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()

p
```

[image]

If you want to add labelled contour lines you could do:

```r
library(geomtextpath)

p + geom_textcontour(aes(z = z, label = ..level..), breaks = 5:9)
```

[image]

---

**Update for three data sets**

This shows which colony has the highest density at which point:

```r
plot_list <- lapply(paste0("my_data_", letters[1:3], ".csv"), 
  function(x) {
    df <- read.csv(x)
    df <- df[order(df$x),]
    radii <- seq(-2, 2, length = 300)
    plot_df <- expand.grid(x = radii, y = radii)
    plot_df$radius <- sqrt(plot_df$x^2 + plot_df$y^2)
    plot_df$z <- df$z[findInterval(plot_df$radius, df$x)]
    plot_df
  })

plot_list[[1]]$fill <- c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")[apply(cbind(plot_list[[1]]$z, 
                          plot_list[[2]]$z, plot_list[[3]]$z), 1, which.max)]

ggplot(plot_list[[1]], aes(x, y, fill = fill)) +
  geom_raster() +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: If you used more flexible smooths with higher degrees of freedom you might approximate the kde2d results.

Comment: @IRTFM depending on the actual data, the above smooth might be the most that could be justified. I suppose if you wanted, you could set `fx = TRUE` and `k = 99` to try to get as much detail back as possible if you knew there was no sampling error in z, though perhaps in that case using `akima::interp` would be the better approach. I'm no expert on GAM smoothers, so I'd be interested to hear your thoughts on how to write a better smoother here.

Comment: Effectively the x-axis data is just radius values (cm) logged ranging from approx c(0,3cm) with 2574 values in-between. I reflected it in terms of c(-3,3) and intensities  have the same amount of values 2574x2 c(3.94-9) ish. When i run the geom_raster command i get : Warning messages:
1: Raster pixels are placed at uneven horizontal intervals and will be shifted. Consider using geom_tile() instead. 
2: Raster pixels are placed at uneven vertical intervals and will be shifted. Consider using geom_tile() instead.

Comment: @CameronWilliamMichaelMurphy that means you should use the second method

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6ZG3.jpg

Comment: Here is a summary of the data: x                 z               y          
 Min.   :-1.4889   Min.   :3.946   Min.   :-1.4889  
 1st Qu.:-0.9993   1st Qu.:4.292   1st Qu.:-0.9993  
 Median : 0.0000   Median :6.673   Median : 0.0000  
 Mean   : 0.0000   Mean   :6.576   Mean   : 0.0000  
 3rd Qu.: 0.9993   3rd Qu.:8.528   3rd Qu.: 0.9993  
 Max.   : 1.4889   Max.   :9.416   Max.   : 1.4889. Plotting it from like a side view looks like this :   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FkBD.png

Comment: @CameronWilliamMichaelMurphy are you able to share the data via a Dropbox or Google docs? Looking again at the image of your data and your description of it, this will require a different approach.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13uEI_dtCx1IBEHZOLmn9j5Qf1KL1zMj5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @CameronWilliamMichaelMurphy thank you. This allows a better approach. I have rewritten my answer to show this.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you so much, makes a lot more sense. The final part of my question above refers to a case when i have 3 dataframes (https://drive.google.com/file/d/10AGfQLvnY98-5tgy_EcplfZGfnaauPcr/view?usp=sharing). If i was say to label A shades of blue, B shades of green and C shades of red. Would it be possible using geom _raster for example to overlay so you can see where A is above B or C and so forth; using the z column as the intensity. Thanks, again for your help. Really, is amazing.

Comment: @AllanCameron I don’t think the data offered supports investigation of more flexible efforts with gam. He doesn’t really have 2d data. The x’s are all equal to the y’s.  He at nest has a single slice through 2d data and is asking for a reconstructed 2d data plot from that. Essentially asking us to manufacture data.

Comment: @IRTFM It turns out the data can be assumed to be radially symmetrical, with x representing distance from the center. The "y" was added unnecessarily. Given these assumptions it is possible to reconstruct the surface, though just with simple interpolation, not with a GAM (see above).

Comment: @Allan Exactly. Just make up data and plot it.

Comment: I just assume radial symmetry, i'm not asking to "make up" too much data. It's great, i was just wondering if it would be possible to have plot a few geom _rasters ontop of each other for A, B & C, with the final image being 3 colours with some penetrating others.

Comment: @CameronWilliamMichaelMurphy using the three data sets doesn't make for a very interesting plot. If you color according to which set is the highest, you get a single flat color representing colony 1, with a small circle of a different color in the center representing colony 2, which has a higher density there. If you overlay the three colonies as red, green and blue, you get a mostly red plot with a blurred white circle in the centre, which isn't very informative. I'll add it to demonstrate

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you, yeah i mean there should be a slight difference in terms of further out from the center. I'm basically wondering if there is a way to present this https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBUX3.jpg in the same way as the density plots above. Effectively showing which colonies have a higher radial distribution. Even if it's just one solid shade and not a continuous one. It's just the attached figure isn't necessarily the easiest for the viewer to interpret. Ideally i'd show that Community C has the higher intensity than A or B further out if you know what i mean.